# CSS Why left rule is given precedence over right rule when there’s a width?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code:

```
#div1{
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 background-color:red;
 position:absolute;
 right:30px !important; 
 left:0px;
 }
```

I want to ask why `left:0px;` overrides `right:30px !important` and not the opposite. Or the one with `!mportant` should override the other, that sounds more logical to me.

As PaulD.Waite pointed out  it’s more that the `left` and `width` rules override the `right` rule.

So the real question is

**Why left is given precedence over right when there’s a width?**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bZ8zg/)

Comment: now take the width off and re-read what you just wrote...

Comment: Having an `!important` in your CSS is almost always a bug. Why do you think you need it ?

Comment: Why do you think overrides `left` `right`? Your example looks like it should. When you remove `width` you see that both are used.

Comment: What was the goal of those contradictory rules ? What are you *really* trying to do ?

Comment: @laaposto: it’s more that the `left` *and* `width` rules override the `right` rule. Without the explicit `width`, both the `left` and `right` rules are honoured: http://jsfiddle.net/mfX2U/1/ I’m not sure *why* `left` is given precedence over `right` when there’s a width. Maybe because the people who wrote the spec were native speakers of left-to-right languages?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite exactly what i am asking here...

Comment: The only really completely correct answer [is down here below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22022287/1729885).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite it's [here in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) and indeed dependent on the [`direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction) property, which defaults to `left` in a browser configured to a Western default language.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: aha, nice one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to show that the browser is w3c compliant:

> If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for ‘left’ (in case the ‘direction’ property of the containing block is ‘rtl’) or ‘right’ (in case ‘direction’ is ‘ltr’) and solve for that value.

So, if we set direction right to left

```
body  {
    direction: rtl;
}

#div1{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    right:30px; 
    left:0px;
}
```

Now left is ignored:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZ8zg/2/)

Answer (score 5):

```
right:30px !important
```

can only override another `right` rule. It can do nothing for your `left` rule.

As long as you don't have other `right` rule, your `!important` has absolutely no effect. It's just used to increase the specificity of the rule, it isn't a kind of hint for the engine on how to deal with various contradictory rules. Once the rules to apply are computed, the role of `!important` is finished.

Comment: Ok. But why left overrides right and not the opposite?

Comment: It doesn't override it. The engine tries to deal with your various rules and doesn't do it the way you imagine it should do. Instead of asking the engine to guess your intent among contradictory rules, write down your real intent in CSS.

Comment: I dont have a real intent. I was just curious to see why this is happening. I mean why the `div` is not placed 30px from right and it is placed 0px from left

Comment: As long as you don't have other `right` rule, your `!important` has absolutely no effect. It's used *before* the engine tries to compose with the contradictory rules, to compute the rules to apply, not *how* to apply them.

Comment: Ok youcan forget the `!important`. So why left is given precedence over right?

Comment: @laaposto Maybe somewhere deep in the spec is it written what to do when you have right, left and width rules but no user should read that. Having those three rules should be considered a bug, just like when you iterate on object properties and rely on a given order.

Answer (score 4):

Having done some more research, the following will answer your question:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#abs-non-replaced-width

> If all three of ‘left’, ‘width’, and ‘right’ are ‘auto’: First set any ‘auto’ values for ‘margin-left’ and ‘margin-right’ to ‘0’. Then, if the ‘direction’ property of the element establishing the static-position containing block is ‘ltr’ set ‘left’ to the static position and apply rule number three below; otherwise, set ‘right’ to the static-position and apply rule number one below.
>
> If none of the three is ‘auto’: If both ‘margin-left’ and ‘margin-right’ are ‘auto’, solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values, unless this would make them negative, in which case when direction of the containing block is ‘ltr’ (‘rtl’), set ‘margin-left’ (‘margin-right’) to ‘0’ and solve for ‘margin-right’ (‘margin-left’). If one of ‘margin-left’ or ‘margin-right’ is ‘auto’, solve the equation for that value. If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for ‘left’ (in case the ‘direction’ property of the containing block is ‘rtl’) or ‘right’ (in case ‘direction’ is ‘ltr’) and solve for that value.
>
> Otherwise, set ‘auto’ values for ‘margin-left’ and ‘margin-right’ to ‘0’, and pick one of the following six rules that apply.
>
> If ‘left’ and ‘width’ are ‘auto’ and ‘right’ is not ‘auto’, then the
> width is shrink-to-fit. Then solve for ‘left’.
>
> If ‘left’ and ‘right’ are ‘auto’ and ‘width’ is not ‘auto’, then if the ‘direction’ property
> of the element establishing the static-position containing block is
> ‘ltr’ set ‘left’ to the static-position, otherwise set ‘right’ to the
> static-position. Then solve for ‘left’ (if ‘direction is ’‘rtl’‘) or
> ’right' (if ‘direction’ is ‘ltr’).
>
> If ‘width’ and ‘right’ are ‘auto’
> and ‘left’ is not ‘auto’, then the width is shrink-to-fit. Then solve
> for ‘right’.
>
> If ‘left’ is ‘auto’, ‘width’ and ‘right’ are not ‘auto’,
> then solve for ‘left’.
>
> If ‘width’ is ‘auto’, ‘left’ and ‘right’ are not ‘auto’, then solve for ‘width’.
>
> If ‘right’ is ‘auto’, ‘left’ and ‘width’ are not ‘auto’, then solve for ‘right’.

Comment: The key phrase (to make it short) is If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for ‘left’ (in case the ‘direction’ property of the containing block is ‘rtl’) or ‘right’ (in case ‘direction’ is ‘ltr’) and solve for that value.

Comment: @vals In the fiddle what ever value i put in the direction rule still left overrides right!

Answer (score 0):

In absolute position rules:

- right = -left
- top = -bottom

Answer (score 0):

Programming/Coding is all about doing things logically and making life easy. 
To answer your question in a simple way, I would say that - You might be thinking that `right:30px;` should override `left:0;` deu to specificity and cascading rule, right? But not here, cascading happens when your both property are same. So, if you write:

```
width: 30px;
width: 50px !important;
```

`width: 50px` is going to get applied.

But in your case, it's left vs right. Not the same property. So, when CSS encounters both of these values, it thinks logically and apply the values. Because if you wanted the element to position just 30px left, you could have written `left: 30px;` and if you wanted the element to position just 30px right, you could have written `right: 30px;` but not both the values in either of the case.

I think you got my point and hope that helps clear your confusion. :)