# Centering page while body{ position:Absolute;}

Tags: html, css

I'm busy on this new website thing, and I run into a problem. Normally, when making the menu, I would just use the entire space, like `100% width` and maybe `100px height` but now, I need just a portion of that, so there is a whitespace next to the menu on both sides.

I tried to get the square, that carries the menu, to the absolute top of the page, most obvious solution:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
```

But now, the square is also moved to the absolute left of the page, instead I want it centered, but I can't get there. This is a piece of my CSS:

```
body, html {    
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbox {
    background-color: #000;
    height:100px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Is there anyone with the solution?

Comment: Is there a good reason why your `body` and `html` are set as `position: absolute`?

Comment: there's no need to position body and html absolutely as they start at the top anyway. If you want `.navbox` centered at the top but positioned absolutely, use `.navbox { position:absolute; top:0; left:50%; margin-left:-350px; ...other styles here }` and position your body realtively

Answer (score 0):

```
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
```

Adjust left and right to suit your desired margins.

Comment: The `left` and `right` properties should no be used together. `left` takes the precedence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990908/css-why-left-rule-is-given-precedence-over-right-rule-when-there-s-a-width

Answer (score -1):

You would probably want to set your left and right to percentages, using 50% for both will center it:

```
#menu {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 70px;
  height:180px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Also, if you are not using absolute positioning you can do the same with this margin-left and margin-right.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m3tsvon/)