# Absolute Positioning with Media Queries

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble styling an absolute element using media queries. Right now I have a box that is positioned at the top left-hand corner of the screen. But, when the screen size is below `768px`, I want this box to stick to the upper right-hand corner. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  div {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

Here's a link to my pen: https://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/ZeNXwz

Thanks!

Comment: Add on the media querie `left:auto`

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990908/css-why-left-rule-is-given-precedence-over-right-rule-when-there-s-a-width

Comment: @DaniP Would you mind deleting this? I did not mean to create a duplicate :)

Comment: I don't have that power mate if you want to be deleted maybe flag for moderator intervention ... But anyway you question is valid don't care about the dupe :) ... I hope the answer posted and the link of the duplicate solved your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  div {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
  }
}
```